# How convert Given DBFS into DB in iOS?

Tags: audio, audio-processing

I am getting DBFS value of an audio ranging from -160 to 1.

I am looking for to create a SPL meter in iOS to show actual DB values of audio capture through mic in device.

Using recorder class, I'm able to be get decibel values which are in DBFS form (-160 to 0).

Is there any way to convert this DBFS value into Actual DB data to represent ?

Comment: there's no such thing as "actual dB". You understand what decibel is, right? If not: wikipedia is your friend. In short: decibel is a relative measurement, so if I say "-3 dB of 1 orange", that's half an orange. If I just say "-3 dB", that doesn't have a meaning, other than saying it's half the integral unit, whatever that was to begin with (oranges, power, energy, µV...).

Comment: (small correction: for µV, that'd be 1/sqrt(2) µV, since that's an amplitude, not a square-amplitude unit)

Comment: Sorry, But i'm new here in sound engineering. I'm not be able to understand your answer.

Comment: It's not an answer, but just a comment. You can't get an answer, because "actual dB" isn't specified. You need to define dB **relative** to something. Maybe you mean "decibel A-weighting"? I don't know! You really need to describe what you mean with "actual" dB!

Comment: I need DB A from DBFS. is it possible?

Comment: not without calibration. For the iPhone, that might be possible, because there's only a few different versions of hardware out there, maybe 20 to 30 or so.

Comment: How can i get calibration for iPhone to obtain correct DB A values?

Comment: You'd get a source of known dB A value in a defined distance, record that with the iphone, apply the A-weighting and calculate a value. (you typically would to this in an anechoic chamber, to avoid echos and external noises influencing the recording) The factor between that and the correct value is what you need to apply every time.

Comment: How can i apply A weighting on given DBFS value ?
Is there any Formula for that or line of code ?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend.

Comment: @Jogasingh No, there is no formula or line of code.

Answer (score 2):

- [**dBFS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS) is a digital signal measurement, relative to full-scale.
- [**dBSPL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level) is a sound pressure level measurement, relative to 20 μPa RMS air pressure.
- **dB(A)** is shorthand for "dBSPL A-weighted", which is the same dBSPL measurement after applying an [A-weighting filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting).

You're going to have to thoroughly understand these concepts before you can convert between them.

Your iPhone has a microphone with an unknown sensitivity, unknown (variable?) gain, and unknown frequency response (which varies with sampling frequency?).  In order to get a reliable SPL measurement from this mic, you need to know all those unknown quantities.  Maybe they can be looked up somewhere, but more likely you'd have to measure them.

Then you would have to design a filter that applies A-weighting as close as possible while counteracting the non-flat response of the mic itself (which may depend on sampling frequency).

If that's reasonably accurate, then you can convert from the recorded dBFS to dBSPL(A) by combining the sensitivity, gain, filter, and ADC range.

Comment: oh, you also need to take into account that phone sound systems really are optimized to *not* record environmental sounds. I'm pretty sure that Apple puts a lot of work into things like source separation and voice enhancement, which might finding a calibration that works for different kinds of signals impossible, if it's enabled by default.

Comment: @MarcusMüller True. I assume there's some lower-level interface available but I don't know.